# Calcular el vencimiento de una factura según varios números de vencimientos

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

En SQL Server 2012 tengo el siguiente código:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Vencimientos') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Vencimientos

DECLARE @FORMA_PAGO AS TABLE (
FormaPago char(10),NumVencimientos int, DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento int, DiasEntreVencimientos int   
,P1 char(10),P2 char(10),FP2 char(10),P3 char(10),FP3 char(10),P4 char(10),FP4 char(10)
)

INSERT INTO @FORMA_PAGO 
VALUES('ALF30',2,0,60,30,70,'TR90','0','0','0','0')
,('4',3,30,60,30,30,NULL,40,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,('TR90',1,90,30,100,0,'0','0','0','0','0')
--,('TR90',2,90,30,50,50,null,0,null,0,null)

select * from @FORMA_PAGO ORDER BY FormaPago

DECLARE @FechaFactura DATE = '20230612' -- Fecha de la factura
DECLARE @FormaPago char(10) = 'alf30' -- ID de la forma de pago
DECLARE @TotalFactura DECIMAL(10, 2) = 1500 -- Total de la factura
,@Dias1Vencimiento int
,@DiasEntreVtos int 

-- Obtener los parciales de pago y la cantidad de vencimientos para la forma de pago seleccionada
DECLARE @P1 char(10), @P2 char(10), @P3 char(10), @P4 char(10), @CantVtos INT
DECLARE @FP2 char(10), @FP3 char(10), @FP4 char(10)
SELECT @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2, @P3 = P3, @P4 = P4, @CantVtos = NumVencimientos,
       @FP2 = FP2, @FP3 = FP3, @FP4 = FP4,@Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento,@DiasEntreVtos = DiasEntreVencimientos 
FROM @FORMA_PAGO
WHERE formapago = @FormaPago

-- Calcular el monto de cada vencimiento
DECLARE @MontoVto DECIMAL(15, 3)
SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P1 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))

-- Calcular la fecha de cada vencimiento
DECLARE @FechaVto DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @Dias1Vencimiento, @FechaFactura)

-- Insertar los vencimientos en una tabla temporal
CREATE TABLE #Vencimientos (FechaVto DATE, Monto DECIMAL(10, 2))

INSERT INTO #Vencimientos (FechaVto, Monto) VALUES (@FechaVto, @MontoVto)

-- Calcular los vencimientos restantes
DECLARE @NumVto INT = 2

WHILE @NumVto <= @CantVtos
BEGIN
    SET @FechaVto = DATEADD(DAY, @DiasEntreVtos, @FechaVto)
    
    IF @NumVto = 2
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@FP2,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP2
            DECLARE @PagoFP2 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP2 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP2
            SET @TotalFactura = @TotalFactura - @montovto
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP2 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))

/*  aqui tendría que preguntar si existiera el P2,P3 y P4 de 'TR90' y así en los @FP siguientes
pero tendría que crear un monton de variables, igual hay alguna otra forma ¿ recursiva ?
*/
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P2 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NumVto = 3
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@FP3,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP3
            DECLARE @PagoFP3 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP3 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP3
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP3 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P3 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NumVto = 4
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@P4,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP4
            DECLARE @PagoFP4 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP4 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP4
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP4 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P4 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P1 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
    END
    
    INSERT INTO #Vencimientos (FechaVto, Monto) VALUES (@FechaVto, @MontoVto)
    
    SET @NumVto = @NumVto + 1
END

-- Consultar los vencimientos
SELECT * FROM #Vencimientos

-- Eliminar la tabla temporal
DROP TABLE #Vencimientos
```

La lógica es calcular las fechas de vencimientos (vtos a partir de ahora) de pagos de una factura. En el caso de la forma '4' los $1500 se pagan en tres plazos y es correcto:

```
Monto   %   fechaVTO
$450    30% 12/07/2023
$450    30% 10/09/2023
$750    50% 09/11/2023
```

el primero son 30 días a partir de la fecha de la factura, el segundo y tercero son 60 días entre vtos. Lo mismo para la forma de pago 'TR90' que quedaría así y también es correcto:

```
Monto   %   fechaVTO
$1500   100 10/09/2023
```

son 90 días para el primer vto después de la fecha de factura y 30 días entre vtos que en este caso sería solo un pago.

Si calculamos ahora los vencimientos para la forma de pago 'ALF30' que tiene un primer vto. del 30% y un segundo vto. del 70% pero para ese segundo vto. la forma de pago es 'TR90' o sea el 70% de la factura hay que fraccionarlo según 'TR90' y el código funciona bien tal cual está ahora 'TR90'

```
Monto   %   fechaVTO
$450    30% 12/06/2023
$1050   70% 09/11/2023
```

Supongamos otra variante para la forma de pago "TR90" que fuera así

```
DELETE @FORMA_PAGO WHERE formapago = 'TR90'
INSERT INTO @FORMA_PAGO 
VALUES('TR90',2,90,30,50,50,null,0,null,0,null)
```

el cálculo para esta forma de pago (TR90) de los $1500 es correcta

```
Monto   %   fechaVTO
$750    50% 10/09/2023
$750    50% 10/10/2023
```

el problema está en la forma 'ALF30', si ejecutamos el código el cálculo de los vencimientos queda así

```
Monto   %           fechaVTO
$450    30%         12/06/2023
$525    50% del 70% 09/11/2023
```

pero faltaría el último vto. es decir

```
Monto   %   fechaVTO
$525    50% del 70% 09/12/2023
```

Espero que lo hayas entendido y que me déis una pista (o la solución ggggg), muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la lógica de lo que hay que hacer? Para no tener que deducirla basados en un código que dices que no funciona correctamente.

Comment: No lo pongas como comentario, edita la publicación para que puedas darle formato.

Comment: ok, así lo haré, gracias

Answer (score 0):

He modificado mi propio código y al parecer funciona con mi ejemplo, fijaos en los comentarios a lo que he agregado al código original. Os pido de favor que si pueden prueben con otras formas de pago inventadas o modificar estas para saber que en general funciona al menos para 4 posibles parciales o vencimientos del pago de una factura, las premisas son las mismas, muchas gracias

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Vencimientos') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Vencimientos

DECLARE @FORMA_PAGO AS TABLE (
FormaPago char(10),NumVencimientos int, DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento int, DiasEntreVencimientos int   
,P1 char(10),P2 char(10),FP2 char(10),P3 char(10),FP3 char(10),P4 char(10),FP4 char(10)
)

INSERT INTO @FORMA_PAGO 
VALUES('ALF30',2,0,60,30,70,'TR90','0','0','0','0')

-----   ESTOS LOS ALTERNO PARA PRUEBAS  ----------------
,('4',3,30,60,30,30,NULL,40,NULL,NULL,NULL)
--,('4',3,30,60,30,30,NULL,40,'TR90',NULL,NULL)
,('TR90',1,90,30,100,0,'0','0','0','0','0')
--,('TR90',2,90,30,50,50,null,0,null,0,null)
--------------------------------------------------------

select * from @FORMA_PAGO ORDER BY FormaPago

DECLARE @FechaFactura DATE = '20230612' -- Fecha de la factura
DECLARE @FormaPago char(10) = 'tr90' -- ID de la forma de pago
DECLARE @TotalFactura DECIMAL(10, 2) = 1500 -- Total de la factura
,@Dias1Vencimiento int
,@DiasEntreVtos int 

-- Obtener los parciales de pago y la cantidad de vencimientos para la forma de pago seleccionada
DECLARE @P1 char(10), @P2 char(10), @P3 char(10), @P4 char(10), @CantVtos INT
DECLARE @FP2 char(10), @FP3 char(10), @FP4 char(10)
SELECT @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2, @P3 = P3, @P4 = P4, @CantVtos = NumVencimientos,
       @FP2 = FP2, @FP3 = FP3, @FP4 = FP4,@Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento,@DiasEntreVtos = DiasEntreVencimientos 
FROM @FORMA_PAGO
WHERE formapago = @FormaPago

-- Calcular el monto de cada vencimiento
DECLARE @MontoVto DECIMAL(15, 3)
SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P1 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))

-- Calcular la fecha de cada vencimiento
DECLARE @FechaVto DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @Dias1Vencimiento, @FechaFactura)

-- Insertar los vencimientos en una tabla temporal
CREATE TABLE #Vencimientos (FechaVto DATE, Monto DECIMAL(10, 2))

INSERT INTO #Vencimientos (FechaVto, Monto) VALUES (@FechaVto, @MontoVto)

-- Calcular los vencimientos restantes
DECLARE @NumVto INT = 2

WHILE @NumVto <= @CantVtos
BEGIN
    SET @FechaVto = DATEADD(DAY, @DiasEntreVtos, @FechaVto)
    
    IF @NumVto = 2
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@FP2,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP2
            DECLARE @PagoFP2 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP2 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP2

------- AGREGADO ------
SET @TotalFactura = @TotalFactura - (SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM #Vencimientos  )
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP2 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))


------- AGREGADO ------
SELECT @Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento FROM  @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP2
SET @FechaVto = DATEADD(DAY, @Dias1Vencimiento, @FechaVto) 
SELECT @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2, @P3 = P3, @P4 = P4, @CantVtos = NumVencimientos,
       @FP2 = FP2, @FP3 = FP3, @FP4 = FP4,@Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento,@DiasEntreVtos = DiasEntreVencimientos 
FROM @FORMA_PAGO
WHERE formapago = @FP2
set @NumVto -= 1
--------------------------------------------

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P2 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NumVto = 3
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@FP3,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP3
            DECLARE @PagoFP3 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP3 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP3
------- AGREGADO ------
SET @TotalFactura = @TotalFactura - (SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM #Vencimientos  )
--------------------------------------------------
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP3 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))

------- AGREGADO ------
SELECT @Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento FROM  @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP3
SET @FechaVto = DATEADD(DAY, @Dias1Vencimiento, @FechaVto) 
SELECT @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2, @P3 = P3, @P4 = P4, @CantVtos = NumVencimientos,
       @FP2 = FP2, @FP3 = FP3, @FP4 = FP4,@Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento,@DiasEntreVtos = DiasEntreVencimientos 
FROM @FORMA_PAGO
WHERE formapago = @FP3
set @NumVto -= 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P3 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NumVto = 4
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@P4,'') <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- Obtener los parciales de pago para FP4
            DECLARE @PagoFP4 DECIMAL(5, 2)
            SELECT @PagoFP4 = P1 FROM @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP4
------- AGREGADO ------
SET @TotalFactura = @TotalFactura - (SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM #Vencimientos  )
---------------------------------------------------
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@PagoFP4 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
------- AGREGADO ------
SELECT @Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento FROM  @FORMA_PAGO WHERE FormaPago = @FP4
SET @FechaVto = DATEADD(DAY, @Dias1Vencimiento, @FechaVto) 
SELECT @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2, @P3 = P3, @P4 = P4, @CantVtos = NumVencimientos,
       @FP2 = FP2, @FP3 = FP3, @FP4 = FP4,@Dias1Vencimiento = DiasHastaPrimerVencimiento,@DiasEntreVtos = DiasEntreVencimientos 
FROM @FORMA_PAGO
WHERE formapago = @FP4
set @NumVto -= 3
---------------------------------------------------

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P4 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @MontoVto = @TotalFactura * (@P1 / CAST(100 AS decimal(10,2)))
    END
    
    INSERT INTO #Vencimientos (FechaVto, Monto) VALUES (@FechaVto, @MontoVto)
    
    SET @NumVto = @NumVto + 1
END

-- Consultar los vencimientos
SELECT * FROM #Vencimientos

-- Eliminar la tabla temporal
DROP TABLE #Vencimientos
```